# Calculating non-uniform current flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, charge

we know $i= \mathrm dq/\mathrm dt$, so $\mathrm dq= i\times\mathrm dt$, thus $q=∫i\,\mathrm dt$

So if given a function relating $t$ and $i$, I can calculate the flow charge. But what about calculating flow of current when I am given a function relating charge (q) with time (t), such as $q=t^2$? Then how do I calculate flow of current I?

I am new to calculus related problems so pardon me if I ask something pointless.

Comment: "we know i= dq/dt ... how do I calculate flow of current I? " Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question itself. $i = \frac{dq}{dt}$. If $q$ is a function of $t$, then you can get $i$ by differentiating $q$ with respect to $t$.

So if we consider your example, $q = t^2$.

Therefore, $i = \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(t^2) = 2t$. Thus in this case current $i$ is a function of $t$, as it varies as $2t$.

You can get the current at any particular time by putting the value of time in the equation.

So if $t = 2 units$, $i = 2.2 = 4 units$.

The current will be constant if $q$ varies linearly with $t$ or may be some other function of $t$ depending on how $q$ varies with $t$.

So basically, you can get the current by following the rules of differentiation.